# How to execute tests based on a parameter defined in services.yaml file in Symfony 6.2

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony6

By defining a parameter `maintenance: true` in services.yaml file, how to run some tests only if `maintenance` is truthy, and some other test only if `maintenance` is falsy?

Note that some tests extends WebTestCase and need to make http requests, so need to booting kernel.

Comment: Did you try [customizing the bootstrap process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/bootstrap.html), initializing the kernel and service container to obtain the parameter and execute tests appropriately?

Comment: Do you want to run specific tests suits? or add "skip test" if maintenance inside each test?

Comment: yes I want to run specific test if that variable is true, and other tests if that variable is false,